# how expose nginx metrics in prometheus?

Tags: docker, prometheus, grafana, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-node-exporter

**so my question is**
*the way to expose Nginx metrics it's only with docker? because I had read in internet and I saw something like this https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter
what I want is to monitor the Nginx log, for failed responses.*

```sh
$ docker run -p 9113:9113 nginx/nginx-prometheus-exporter:0.8.0 -nginx.scrape-uri http://<nginx>:8080/stub_status
```

Comment: Hi. I am not sure what seems to be unclear here. The docs clearly show a non-docker way of using the nginx-exporter https://github.com/nginxinc/nginx-prometheus-exporter#running-the-exporter-binary

Comment: I'm sorry it's my first time and I felt a bit lost among so much info, I was looking for a way to export the Nginx metrics

Comment: Lets look at what we need. We need to get Nginx "metrics" and then "export" it to Prometheus. How do I get the metrics? if you can either use Nginx auto-created metrics or figure out some other way to create them. How do I send them to Prometheus? First, you have to convert the metrics into a format that Prometheus would like. then its an easy thing to actually send it.

Comment: the nginx-prometheus-exporter is a binary that aims to automate all of this. it would take the inbuilt Nginx metrics, convert it to Prometheus format and then send it across. Now, does this satisfy your requirements, then great! otherwise, you can modify the code or create your own solution

Comment: Finally, i just noticed your last comment. "I want to monitor Nginx logs...". My bad. The nginx-prometheus-exporter will not really help here. What you instead need is a tool that can read logs in real time, parse and understand a pattern (ex: looking for failed response) and then send it to Prometheus. Maybe look into the ELK stack if it makes sense

Comment: so if it would be to make your own file script that constantly reads the log I want and then send it to promethus, but not as a node

Comment: yep. that should be the easiest. Do check out the ELK family of tools for log aggregation and parsing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To summarize our discussion in the comments:

1. The `node-prometheus-exporter` is handy tool to get the Nginx in-built metrics and send it to Prometheus. But if you need any specialised metric, you have to either modify the source code or create your own solution.
2. I think you specifically want to *check Nginx logs for failed responses*. This warrants a log aggregation and/or parsing tool and the corresponding connection to Prometheus. For this you can look at the ELK family for something nice or built a quick script yourself.